# Unable to upload Image on live site

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a site where there is member registration. All data will be saved but I get only this error:

```
Could not move the file "/tmp/phpa4pH3I" to "/home/sporter/public_html/someonect.org/uploads\membersImages/33921.jpg" ()
```

My code is like this

```
public function store(){
    // dd(Input::all());
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Members::$rules);

    if($validator->passes()):

        $first_name = Input::get('mem_firstName');
        $last_name = Input::get('mem_lastName');
        $email = Input::get('mem_email');
        $image = Input::get('mem_image');
        $phone = Input::get('mem_phone');
        $occupation = Input::get('mem_occupation');
        $citizen = Input::get('mem_citizen');
        $address = Input::get('mem_address');

        $destinationPathImage = str_replace('PROJECT\\', '', base_path().'\uploads\membersImages\\') ;

        //Generating a random name
        $randomName = rand(11111,99999);

        //Renaming the image
        $ImageName = $randomName.'.'.'jpg'; // renameing image

        $imagePath = $destinationPathImage.$ImageName;

        Members::create([
                'first_name'=>$first_name,
                'last_name'=>$last_name,
                'email'=>$email,
                'image'=>$imagePath,
                'phone'=>$phone,
                'occupation' => $occupation,
                'citizen' => $citizen,
                'address'=>$address
        ]);
        ...
```

Comment: Do you have write permissions on your folders?

Comment: yes i have write permission

Comment: it seems like the slashes in the path are wrong `someonect.org/uploads\membersImages`

Comment: i used back ward and frontward slashes but it is not working ie file not moved to folder but saved in database

Comment: Please add your upload script to your question!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understrand clearly your `str_replace` part, but if you setup your url in config properly, you don't need this.

I'm using this kind of upload for an image:

```
if($request->hasFile('mem_image')) {
   $file = $request->file('mem_image');
   $ext = $request->file('mem_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $filename = rand(11111,99999). '.' . $ext;
   $file->move('./uploads/', $filename);
   $member->mem_image = '/uploads/' . $filename;
   $member->save();
}
```

In case, your `uploads` directory is in your public folder.

Answer (score 0):

If your script have permission for writing in target folder. The problem can be only in path.  Check what contain in variable $destinationPathImage. It must be correct and exists path.  In your error message I see problem with slashes.

also think that it's be cool to check exists of destination folder and file exists before save to database record with path of file.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the proper slashes.

Replace `\uploads\membersImages\\` with `/uploads/membersImages/`.

If it still not working, please double check the permissions in that folder using the is_writable php function. However, have in mind that the is_writable function is not working properly on windows platforms.